# Follow-up 1: Compare 2 unordered, rooted trees for shape-isomorphism

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, recursion, tree

[The previous post can be found here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/160907/compare-2-unordered-rooted-trees-for-shape-isomorphism/160923#160923).

In the previous post I tried to solve an exercise but found through the answer of Peilonrayz a bug in the code and 2 more while fixing it. These have now been amended (changes to the original code can be seen in my answer in the previous question).

**The exercise** (Copy&Paste from the previous question)

> Write a program to check if 2 int arrays of N whole numbers between 0
>   and N-1 represent 2 isomorphic unordered trees, if you interpret the
>   arrays as predecessor-successor-connections in a tree (e.g. in an int
>   array index 3 has value 5. That means the node with value 3 is child
>   of the node with value 5) , while the nodes are numbered from 0 to
>   N-1. That means, your program should determine if there is a way to
>   re-number the nodes in a tree, so that the array-representation of one
>   tree is identical to the array-representation of the other tree.

Sidenote: I interpreted this as: "Check for tree-isomorphism between 2 trees given in int arrays". I believe this also means that one needs to check if one tree can be re-arranged in any fashion, so that shape-isomorphism occurs.

**The Algorithm** (Copy&Paste from the previous question)

> 1. Recreate the trees from the array using Node objects. Each node object contains its value called value and an ArrayList of node
>      references called children
> 2. Sort the nodes in the unordered trees according to the amount of children, further called nChildren , they have directly connected to
>      them. Sort left to right in descending order. Go from left to right,
>      start sorting at the leaves and work your way up. If 2 sibling-nodes
>      n1 and n2 have identical nChildren, compare the nChildren of their
>      children from largest to lowest. If no difference is found, compare
>      the the nChildrenof their children, again from largest to lowest.
>      Repeat until difference is found or you find that these already sorted
>      sub-trees that have n1 and n2 as roots have shape-isomorphism. In that
>      case their order is irrelevant.
> 3. Compare the two now sorted trees and check for shape-isomorphism. Go recursively through the two trees in post-Order. Possible Cases: 1)
>      Both currently observed nodes are leaves 2) The two observed nodes
>      have unequal nChildren (e.g. one is a leaf while the other isn't) 3)
>      Both observed nodes have equal nChildren. 1) and 2) are the base
>      cases. If at any point one method call returns false, return false for
>      all calls that lead to calling this iteration of the method. Else
>      return true.

(2 Examples for the sorting can be found in the previous question).

**The code**

```
package Kapitel5;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Test {
    static class Node {
        int value;
        ArrayList<Node> children;

        Node(int value, ArrayList<Node> children) {
            this.value = value;
            this.children = children;
        }
    }

    static class NodeComparator implements Comparator<Node> {
        public NodeComparator() {
        }

        public int compare(Node n1, Node n2) {
            /*-
             * Case1: Both Nodes have unequal amounts of nodes 
             * -> return (-) 1
             * Case2: Both Nodes have equal amounts of nodes 
             * -> test child-nodes or return 0 if that is impossible;
             */
            if (n1.children.size() != n2.children.size()) {// BaseCase2
                return ((n1.children.size() > n2.children.size()) ? -1 : 1);
            } else {
                /*
                 * If n1 and n2 have equal amounts of children, compare the
                 * amounts of children their children have, from largest to
                 * lowest. If the default assumption is ever wrong, do not
                 * perform further comparisons.
                 */
                int result = 0; /*- Default assumption - Sub-trees of n1 and n2 are equal*/
                for (int i = 0; (i < n1.children.size()) && (result == 0); i++) {
                    result = compare(n1.children.get(i), n2.children.get(i));
                }
                return result;
            }
        }
    }

    static final NodeComparator comp = new NodeComparator();

    static void sortForest(Node root) {
        if (root.children.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < root.children.size(); i++) {
                sortForest(root.children.get(i));
            }
            root.children.sort(comp);
        }
    }

    static void removeRootFromChildren(Node root) {
        int i = 0;
        while (root.children.get(i) != root) {
            i++;
        }
        root.children.remove(i);
    }

    static Node createTreeFromArray(int[] tree) {
        Node[] treeNodes = new Node[tree.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < tree.length; i++) {
            treeNodes[i] = new Node(i, new ArrayList<Node>(15));
        }
        Node root = null;
        /*-Fill the ArrayLists of each Node with references to their child-Nodes*/
        for (int i = 0; i < tree.length; i++) {
            treeNodes[tree[i]].children.add(treeNodes[i]);
            if (tree[i] == i) {
                root = treeNodes[i];
            }
        }
        /* Ascertain that tree has root */
        if (root == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Given tree-array has no root!");
        } else {
            /*
             * Trees are given in format where roots point at themselves and are
             * therefore listed as children in their own ArrayList. Remove it.
             */
            removeRootFromChildren(root);
            return root;
        }
    }

    static boolean compareTrees(Node nodeFromTree1, Node nodeFromTree2) {
        /*-
         * Case1: Both Nodes have unequal amounts of nodes 
         * -> return false;
         * Case2: Both Nodes have equal amounts of nodes 
         * -> test child-nodes or return true if that is impossible;
         */
        if (nodeFromTree1.children.size() != nodeFromTree2.children.size()) {
            return false;
        } else {
            boolean treesAreIsomorph = true; // Default Assumption
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeFromTree1.children.size() && treesAreIsomorph; i++) {
                treesAreIsomorph = compareTrees(nodeFromTree1.children.get(i), nodeFromTree2.children.get(i));
            }
            return treesAreIsomorph;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int[] tree1 = { 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 0, 7, 5, 3, 10, 10, 6 };
        int[] tree2 = { 4, 10, 11, 0, 4, 0, 12, 4, 7, 8, 0, 3, 4, 12 };

        Node root1 = createTreeFromArray(tree1);
        Node root2 = createTreeFromArray(tree2);
        sortForest(root1);
        sortForest(root2);
        System.out.println(compareTrees(root1, root2));
    }
}
```

The given trees in the code should and do return "true" when given to `compareTrees()`.

**Questions** (Copy&Paste from the previous question)

Question No. 2 got solved in the previous post.

> 1. Should I have avoided the static NodeComparator variable? I used it since, in the end, it saved me a lot of instantiating of an object
>      to pass to ArrayLists sort() method. I don't know as of now how to do
>      the sorting with the provided sort() without passing an object.
> 2. [...]
> 3. Was the algorithm I thought of acceptable or should I have gone for a different approach? If yes, please explain which one, this was
>      the only one I could think of.
>
> I'd appreciate it if reviews of the code itself focused especially on
>   the recursive methods, since I think that's the part where I'm
>   struggling the most.